# String Concatenation with '+' not working in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

**Edit**: Full script is just two lines now. This used to work and stopped working after I once changed jdk.

**`+` not working to concatenate strings (full script)**

```
output = "hello" + "," + "world"
println output
```

**Output**

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>
> Script1.hello() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String)
>
> values: [,] Possible solutions: getAt(java.lang.String), sleep(long),
>
> each(groovy.lang.Closure), split(groovy.lang.Closure)     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:81)

**Although the concat function works fine**

```
output = ("hello".concat(",")).concat("world")
println output
```

Comment: How is `output` declared? What type is `u`? What type does `u.getId()` return? How is `email` declared, and what does it contain?

Comment: Just to have it mentioned: the idiomatic way to write that in groovy would be `"${u.id},${email}"`

Comment: @ChrisLong, it doesn't matter as they are strings. I tried with "hello" +"," +"world" still same

Comment: Edited to make it more general

Comment: @cfrick, The + should also work. I don't know what broke.

Comment: Well, clearly that does work, in a working Groovy installation, so there is something badly wrong with your installation (I assume you're running `def output = 'hello' + 'world'` as a standalone script in a new Groovy session). You may need to reinstall Groovy.

Comment: Yes - it should and it does. Please add the groovy version you are using and also what environment you are running this in.

Comment: The error happens `at Script1.groovy line 11). I believe that problem not in concatenation. Show what do you have at line 11, and better whole script.

Comment: This looks fishy: `No signature of method: java.lang.String.,()` The dot comma parens. Show your code, especially line 11

Comment: No need for downvotes. This is a genuine error. it used to work before but now all I did was changed jdk and it is not working.

Comment: @daggett, updated code to have just two lines, updated error too.

Comment: This is the way it is being called/run  curl -d "script=$(cat Script.groovy)" -v --user xxx:xxxx http://jenkinsserver/scriptText

Comment: cat script.groovy                                                                                                                                                             
output = "hello" + "," + "world"
println output

Comment: maaan, you have to specify in your question how and what you are calling. definitely you have problem in your command line and not in script!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** I don't know `Jenkin-Groovy` much.

```
Script1.hello() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String)
```

The above line, in your error trace, implies that it's taking your string `"hello"`, as a method, in `Script1`. Precisely, it's trying to execute, sort of, `Script1.hello(String s)`, by passing `","` as an argument. Since, there is none, it throws an error.

I'm not sure but how about trying this, instead

```
output = 'hello' + ',' + 'world'
println output
```

NB: There is a [difference](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#all-strings) in single-quoted (`String`) and double-quoted (`GString`) in Groovy

Or, this

```
hello = 'hello'
world = 'world'
output = "$hello, $world"
println output
```

Answer (score 1):

this question about `shell` and [jenkins api](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-console/#remote-access). and not about `groovy`...

after injecting of script body in shell instead of `$(cat ...)` you get the following command line

```
-d "script=output = "hello" + "," + "world""
```

that is wrong `url-encoded` parameter

try `--data-urlencode` instead of `-d`

```
curl --data-urlencode "script=$(cat Script.groovy)" ...
```

probably you have to play with doublequotes after that...